# Adding description of marker on google map

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have several markers with different colors, every color is used for specific purpose(like user's location etc). for each color I want to add short description of marker on the map.Is it possible to add short description of color on google map in right side corner?

Comment: go to google maps docs

Comment: this is possible and very easy to do that. on top of map create one layout in top and show and hide as per your condition.

Answer (score 0):

In your layout file of map you can add any thing apart from `MapFragment`. but ensure that in your xml add other views after Mapfragment then they will appear above map fragment.

Comment: I want to use description inside the mapFragment, is it possible?